# Ocultar div quando input on focus, css

Tags: css

Como posso esconder minha div quando a input estiver em focus? Usei este cod e nao me deu certo

```
.A:focus  .B {
    display: inline-block !important;
}
```

Comment: com css apenas isso não será possivel, você irá inserir um onfocus no input que é um tipo javascript apontando para uma função e nesta função você irá criar um elemento de css para a div que deseja

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer algo assim:

```css
div {
     background: #f0a;
     display: true;
     height: 200px;
     width: 200px; }

input:focus + div { display: none }
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/zyw3s14o/)</kbd>

Você pode utilizar classes ou identificadores assim:

```css
div.hidden {
background: #f0a;
display: true;
height: 200px;
width: 200px; }
input.focus:focus + div.hidden { display: none }
```

E então adicionar o HTML assim:

```html
<input class="focus" type="text" value="">
<div class="hidden"></div>
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/zyw3s14o/1/)</kbd>

Comment: nossa, nunca vi este método, muito bom mesmo, eu usava o onFocus="eventtipsignupnomefocus()" onBlur="eventtipsignupnomeblur()", este é muito manero

Comment: @flourigh o css está incrível quando se sabe usar..

Comment: @user3715916 pois é rapaz, nunca tentei utilizar, pois sempre fiz com JavaScript então nunca procurei, mas agora adorei este método que inclusive funciona de muitas formas, muito bom, isso é do CSS3? correto

Comment: @flourigh [CSS2](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_focus.asp).